# Dynamic Programming Scope of Variable with python for the SubSets problem

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, scope, dynamic-programming

I'm learning dynamic programming. I recently found this code to compute the amount of subsets which sum is equal to a given number. But I can't understand how mem value gets updated.

```
def count_sets(arr,total):
    mem = {}
    return dp(arr,total,len(arr)-1, mem)

def dp(arr,total, i, mem):
    key = str(total)+':'+str(i)
    if key in mem:
        return mem[key]
    if total == 0:
        return 1
    elif total < 0 or i < 0:
        return 0
    elif total < arr[i]:
        to_return = dp(arr,total, i-1, mem)
    else: 
        to_return = (dp(arr,total - arr[i], i-1, mem) \
        + dp(arr,total, i-1, mem))

    mem[key] = to_return
    return to_return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = count_sets([2,4,6,10],16)
    print(c) # print 2
```

I though the first call of  dp(arr,total, i, mem) in the algorthm has {} for mem.

So if I'm only returning the amount of subsets so far (also known as to_return), why is mem being update if it's not returning, shouldn't its value only live in the scope of the function?

Could someone help me better understand the scope of the variable mem? and why it gets updated? thanks!

Another Example I tried to understand was:

```
def add(x):
    x = x+1

def main():
    a = 2
    add(a)
    print(a)#prints 2

main()
```

Comment: Your first code print out 2 not 4 though.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I already fixed it @Frank

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-functions-modify-lists-dictionaries-python/

Comment: Yes, is all clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question for future readers, thanks to @Frank I found out there are either mutable ( integers, floats, strings, Booleans, and tuples) or immutable (list, dictioanry)  datatypes in python. 
So global list or dictionary can be changed even when it’s used inside of a function, that's why the variable mem in my code is modified through the algorithm.